# Google search scraper , Python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am new to Python and trying to make a Google search scraper for the purpose of getting stock prices , but I run my code below I dont get any results instead I am getting the page HTML formatting.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = 'https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=uwti'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

Am I missing something very simple , please give me some pointers on this . I am trying to extract the current stock value.How do I extract this value in the attached image ?

[image]

Comment: It appears to be getting the price and displaying it dynamically, probably using Javascript, so it doesn't appear in the HTML you receive from BeautifulSoup. I think you will need to take a different approach. There are plenty of good Python options to download stock data from Yahoo or Google, try looking into those.

Comment: @jeffcarey, it is in the source if the request is made correctly, there is no Javascript involved.

Answer (score 3):

It is in the source when you right-click and choose view-source in your browser. You just need to change the *url* slightly and pass a *user-agent* to match what you see there using requests:

```
In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   ...: import requests
   ...: 
   ...: url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=uwti&rct=j'
   ...: response = requests.get(url, headers={
   ...:     "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K
   ...: HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"})
   ...: html = response.content
   ...: 
   ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
   ...: print(soup.select_one("span._Rnb.fmob_pr.fac-l").text)
   ...: 
27.51
```

`soup.find("span", class_="_Rnb fmob_pr fac-l").text` would also work and is the correct way to look for a tag using the *css classes* with find or *find_all*

You can see in chrome when you use https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=uwti, there is a redirect to https://www.google.com/search?q=uwti&rct=j:

[image]

Comment: Padraic, Can you give me some pointers on how to establish/find the details on headers that you have mentioned in request.get

Comment: @Fenomatik,  when you enter *https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=uwti* youcan see it becomes *https://www.google.com/search?q=uwti&rct=j* in your broswer, if you watch the request in chrome tools you can see it all happening. Sending a user-agent is pretty standard and often required when scraping a site.

Comment: I tried to use dev tools in Chrome but I coudnt find any GET requests like you found ? there were mostly POST requests. Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: It is definitely there, make sure you are checking under the XHR tab and you make the request after you open tools.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) to your request so Google would treat your request as a real user visit because the default `requests` `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and Google understands it and blocks requests thus you receive a different HTML with some sort of an error. [List of user-agents](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/). [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).
2. Use [SelectorGadget](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb) Chrome extension to quickly find and grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser. `CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).
3. Use extracted `CSS` selector using [`.select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) `bs4` method to get the data.

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Scrape-Answer-Box-Stocks-Data-python#bs4_result.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=spgsclp', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

current_stock_price = soup.select_one('.wT3VGc').text
print(current_stock_price)

# 108,52
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The biggest difference in your case is that you don't have to figure out why something doesn't work and figuring out how to scrape this data. The process of getting the data is much clearer.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "spgsclp",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

current_stock_price = results['answer_box']['price']
print(current_stock_price)

# 108,52
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Comment: It's better to use a fresh user-agent. Google blocks old user agents much earlier. See https://user-agents.top for a fresh list

Comment: @MikhailYevchenko Thanks for mentioning this  There's also a [whatismybrowser](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/) website that shows your current user-agent. Or even better use a library that updates them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `Beautiful Soup's` [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) on how to select elements of the HTML document you just parsed you could try something like:

`soup.findAll("span", ['_Rnb', 'fmob_pr, 'fac-l'])`

The above method will find the span element that implements the classes in the list.

FYI: The stock price does not get fetched by the initial request from what I can see, use the `Inspect Element` feature of your browser to capture the requests sent, from what I can see there is a request to the url `https://www.google.gr/async/finance_price_updates`. Maybe this is used to fetched the price for the stock, see if you can sent requests to it directly rather than fetching the whole HTML.

Answer (score 0):

google will not give you to scrape it so you have to use some API or just change site of stocks.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'siteurl'
response = urllib.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

print(soup.findAll("div", { "class" : 'classname' }))
```

you can use this code just by changing 'siteurl' and 'classname'(which you have to scrape)